# JBoss deployment

Tags: jboss6.x

We are trying to deploy a WAR on JBoss through Eclipse. The WAR is getting deployed in workspace folder and not being copied to deploy folder of JBoss.
hence,The application is also not running.
please,tell what could be the possible solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Eclipse, follow these steps :

- Double click on Jboss Server in Server mode (Window > Preferences, then Open Server perspective)
- The **Jbos Server Overview** window will be opened
- Choose the **Deployment** tab, update default settings
- By default, the choice **Use the workspace metadata** will be selected.
- Change to Jboss - Jboss deploy folder.

Your problem will be solved. It will place the ear file into deploy folder.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to work with the JBoss tools recently. I tried to deploy EAR projects to a JBoss As 6.x, but failed to do so using the eclipse plugins...

What I do now is this:
I created an 'external tool configuration' (this is right next to the green arrow for 'run configurations'. This tool configuration I configured in a way so it deploys my project for me:

**Location:**
`/bin/cp`

**Working Directory:**
`${workspace_loc:/project/location_of_your_war_file}`

**Arguments:**
`${workspace_loc:/project/location_of_your_war_file/project.war} /path/to/jboss/server/default/deploy/`

This just uses the /bin copy tool to deploy your project. Sadly I have been forced to work like this for some time, as the JBoss Eclipse plugins tend to seem quite full of bugs (and also are not up to date with the latest Eclipse verions most of the time...).